# Настройка зависимости в VS 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Пробую создать проект по [инструкции](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/cross-platform/learn-app-building-basics-with-xamarin-forms-in-visual-studio).

Использую VS 2017 Community Edition, через VS installer поставил .NET Core 2.0.

Создаю новый проект Библиотека классов (.Net standarts), а в завимостях проекта все равно стоит Core Platforms 1.1.0. Как изменить зависимость на версию 2.0?

То же самое в Xamarin из-за чего не могу поставить некоторые пакеты (в инструкции: Microsoft.Net.Http), так как они требуют версию библиотеки 2.0

Вот как у меня выглядит окно создания проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Ошибок две.

По ошибке связанной с типом проекта. Проект Core и NetStandard - это разные типы проектов, вы их потом друг с другом не подружите.

Если у вас solution построен на базе .Net core - то когда вам нужно добавить проект типа class library - то вам нужно добавлять проект тоже core.

class library есть и в core:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и в .net standard:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так, теперь по второй ошибке.

Внимательно смотрите на зависимости при установке проекта. У вас проект на базе .net core - поэтому и nuget-пакеты должны поддерживать core.

Пакет Microsoft.Net.Http. не поддерживается в core:

```
This package includes HttpClient for sending requests over HTTP, as well as HttpRequestMessage and HttpResponseMessage for processing HTTP messages.

This package is not supported in Visual Studio 2010, and is only required for projects targeting .NET Framework 4.5, Windows 8, or Windows Phone 8.1 when consuming a library that uses this package.

Supported Platforms:
- .NET Framework 4
- Windows 8
- Windows Phone 8.1
- Windows Phone Silverlight 7.5
- Silverlight 4
- Portable Class Libraries
```

Вам нужно ставить System.Net.Http версии не ниже 4.3.3

См. также вопрос на SOen:

- [System.Net.Http vs Microsoft.Net.Http](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31053243/5752652)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75673/discussion-on-answer-by-a-k----vs-2017).